# Solution to a Hadamard product least squares

Tags: optimization, least-squares, hadamard-product

Given two full-rank matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and vectors $y \in \mathbb{R}^n, u \in \mathbb{R}^p, v \in \mathbb{R}^k$ I'd like to solve an optimization problem of the form

$$ \arg\min_{u, v} \|y - (A u) \circ (Bv)\|^2$$

where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product (aka elementwise product) and the norm is the euclidean vector norm.

I can find the solution by alternate minimization (iteratively fixing one variable and solving for the other one), but it is terribly slow.In practice I have a lot of these problems where the $y$ varies but $A, B$ are always the same so ideally I would like to express the solution in terms of a matrix factorization of $A$ and/or $B$.

My question is: has this problem been addressed somewhere in the literature? Is it possible to find a closed form solution in terms of a matrix factorization of $A, B$ analogous to the (ordinary) least squares?

Comment: The dude's name is HadamarD.

Comment: Have you tried standard solvers or packages? Have you tried Gauss-Newton for nonlinear least squares?

I haven't tried to compute the jacobian of $(Au)*(Bv)$, but it shouldn't be that complicate, as the function is bilinear.

Comment: Note that what I am asking for are either pointers to the literature where this problem has been addressed or a closed form solution.

Comment: I suspect there might be no closed-form solution for this problem since the problem isn't convex and there doesn't seem to be a nice transformation (at least at a first glance) which would make it so. Perhaps your best bet might be to just to alternating optimization, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Here I'd change $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^p, \ \beta \in \mathbb{R}^k$ just for notation coherence.

One way to transform this problem into an ordinary least squares (OLS) is:

We have our main problem with Hadamard product:

$$
 \begin{equation}
 \text{argmin}_{\alpha,\beta}\|y - \bar{y} \|_2^2,   \ \ \ (1)
 \end{equation}
$$

were $\bar{y} = (A\alpha \odot B\beta)$ is our approximation vector.

We can rewrite each row of our approximation vectos as:

$$
  \bar{y}_i = \left( A_i \alpha \right)\left(B_i \beta\right),
$$

where $A_i$ and $B_i$ denotes the $i^\text{th}$ row of the corfesponding matrix.

Just changing the notation, we have
$$
\begin{align}
  \bar{y}_i & = \left(\begin{array}{l l l}
  a_{i,1} B_i, \ldots, a_{i,p} B_i
\end{array} 
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{}
 \alpha_1 \beta \\
 \vdots \\
 \alpha_p \beta
\end{array}
\right),
\end{align}
$$

$$
 (A\alpha \odot B\beta)_i = (A_i \otimes B_i)(\alpha \otimes \beta), 
$$

where $\otimes$ denotes the kronecker product.

Using this equality we can define our new design matrix as $ H_i = (A_i \otimes B_i )$, and solution vector as $x = (\alpha \otimes \beta)$, then we can solve the OLS:

$$
 \text{argmin}_{x}\|y - Hx\|_2^2,
$$

finding our global solution, due the convexity in $x$.

In order to retrieve the solution vectors, can rewrite $x$ as a matix, for instance, product of our solution vectors $\alpha$ and $\beta$,

$$
X = \left( \begin{array}{lcr}
            \alpha_1 \beta_1 & \ldots & \alpha_1 \beta_k \\
            \alpha_2 \beta_1 & \ldots & \alpha_2 \beta_k\\
            \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
            \alpha_p \beta_1 & \ldots & \alpha_p \beta_k
           \end{array}
    \right) = \alpha \beta^T 
$$

We use the singular value decomposotion (SVD) to represent our matrix, as

$$
 X=U\Sigma V^T,
$$

as $Rank(X)=1$, then using the first left and right singular vectors $u$ and $v$, and the first singular value $\sigma$,

$$
 \bar{\alpha} = \gamma\sqrt\sigma u, \ \ \text{and} \ \ \bar{\beta} = \frac{1}{\gamma}\sqrt\sigma v,
$$

where $\gamma$ depends of the scale of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and also the bias, $|\gamma|>0$.

The vectors solutions are scale sensitive, so the solution is not unique and additional assumptions should be made.

Hope this will be usefull

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you are assuming that the least squares solution on $H$ followed by the best rank-1 approximation to that solution will be the global solution, which is generally not the case. More formally, you are assuming that $\text{argmin}\|y - X (\alpha \otimes \beta)\|$ = $\text{argmin}\|X^{\dagger} y - (\alpha \otimes \beta)\|$ which is in general not true (take for example H = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0]], y = [1, 2], with your solution the residual is 0.23 but the solution (1, 1), (-2, 1.5) has zero residual)

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
&e = Au,\qquad &de = A\,du,\qquad &E = \Diag e = E^T \\
&f = Bv,\qquad &df = B\,dv,\qquad &F = \Diag f = F^T \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
&w = \LR{e\circ f-y} \;=\; \LR{Ef-y} \;=\; \LR{Fe-y} \\
}$$
The Frobenius product is a convenient way to write
the trace and the norm
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different
but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\&= \LR{A^TC}:B \\\\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to write the objective function and calculate its gradients.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \frac 12\;{w:w} \\
d\phi &= {w}:{dw} \\
 &= {w}:\LR{F\,de + E\;df} \\
 &= {Fw}:{de} + {Ew}:{df} \\
 &= {Fw}:\LR{A\,du} + {Ew}:\LR{B\,dv} \\
 &= {A^TFw}:{du} + {B^TEw}:{dv} \\
\grad{\phi}{u} &= {A^TFw},\qquad\grad{\phi}{v} = {B^TEw} \\
}$$
Set the first gradient to zero and calculate the least squares solution
$$\eqalign{
0 &= A^TFw = A^TF\LR{FAu-y} \qiq
 u_* = \LR{FA}^+y \\
}$$
where $\LR{FA}^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $\LR{FA}\,$ however in Matlab code it is more efficient to use the backslash operator
$\;u_* = (FA)\,\backslash\,y$

Depending on the relative dimensions of the variables (which weren't fully specified), it may be possible to drastically simplify this calculation.

In particular if
$$p \ge n = {\rm rank}(A) = {\rm rank}(F)$$
then
$$\LR{FA}^+ = A^+F^+ \qiq u_* = A^+\LR{y\oslash f}$$
Since $A^+$ can be computed **once** outside of the main loop and since the Hadamard division $(\oslash)$ of vectors is extremely fast, this approach is even more efficient than the previously mentioned backslash operator.

Analogous manipulations of the second gradient yields
$\;v_* = \LR{EB}^+y$

The conventional Alternating Least Squares (ALS) iterations are then
$$\eqalign{
E &= \Diag{Au} \\
v &= \LR{EB}^+y \\
F &= \Diag{Bv} \\
u &= \LR{FA}^+y \\
}$$
However, simple substitution will eliminate one of the variables and yield a nonlinear equation (NLE) in the remaining variable, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
{u} &= \LR{\Diag{B\LR{\Diag{A\c{u}}B}^+y}A}^+y \\
u &= G(\c{u}) \\
F(u) &= {u-G(u)} \;=\; 0 \\
}$$
This NLE can be solved using a quasi-Newton (or conjugate gradient) method, which will have a faster ***rate*** of convergence than ALS. The trade-off for this increased speed is the loss of the convergence guarantee of the ALS iteration.

Furthermore, such an approach requires the Jacobian of $F(u)$ which is far too complicated to calculate manually and will require the use of Automatic Differentiation (AD) software.